# Proving that flux contribution due to rotation is zero for a triangular loop welded to infinite wire set up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, vector-fields

> Consider a triangular loop attached at the vertex to an infinitely long wire which has time varying current flowing in the +x direction
>
> [image]
>
> Adapted from JEE advanced paper-1  2016

One may find that the contribution due to the current varying is given as:

$$ V= \frac{\mu_o d}{\pi} \frac{di}{dt}$$

But now, suppose the set up is rotated about the axis of wire, what extra EMF would be generated? Apparently the answer is zero but I find it a bit tricky to understand. So far, I understand that this is due to $\vec{B}$ by the wire being a function of $r$ and hence all point at same distance of axis is equivalent (at least to the magnetic field).

I need to show some how prove that, if we were to rotate the set up about the vertex, then the $\vec{B}$  field at all points in the interior of the triangle would be the same as the original unrotated configuration for all possible rotation angles.

Preferably, I wish for a mathematical explanation but a physical one is fine as well if it detailed.

Comment: i think one way to think this is that while rotating the triangle the direction of emf induced changes. try placing the triangle at opposite positions(i rotated the triangle π radians) and you will find that direction of emf induced is also opposite. (by lenz law) ,So in one complete rotation,the emf induced should be $0$ but instantaneous emf should not be zero.

Comment: @TanishaDaharwal I disagree, suppose you fix the area vector to point in some direction in the start, now after that rotation, it would point in the opposite direction if you are consistent with the orientation you had took of the area

Comment: yes you are right,my mistake.

Comment: how is the current varying in the wire ,is it linear or sinusoidal like AC current? because if its AC current the emf will have a cos(wt) part in it whose average value over a complete rotation is 0. otherwise, i fail to understand why the emf induced must be zero if the variation of current is not sinusoidal.

Comment: The variation in flux due to current directly is already captured by the expression in question, the problem is to find the additional variation if it is rotating. @TanishaDaharwal and for the second part, yeah, I find it too and that's why I asked xD

Comment: I've added an answer @TanishaDaharwal

Answer (score 1):

Since then magnetic field produced by a current in the long wire forms circular loops around the wire, a rotation of the triangle around the wire would not result in a change in the flux.

Answer (score 0):

I have drawn the set up in four different configurations upon rotation.

[image]

The black arrow is the area vector, and x is a point marked inside the triangle. We see that under rotations about the axis, the perpendicular distance from the axis to points inside the triangle remains fixed eg: the distance to x is fixed. This needs a proof but it's geometrically intuitive.

For more intuition, see that each point in the triangle moves in a circle cantered at the axis, and the B vector field is tangent to this circle at every point.

Comment: I think so the area vector may be tangent to the mentioned circle as well but I am not sure how one would show it

Comment: If the wire is thin and in the plane of the triangle (as in the sketch), then the plane of the triangle must be radial and the area vector is tangential.